# Speed of light and time dilation vs. mass and time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light

Time slows for an observer the faster they come to the speed of light, large amounts of mass also also have an effect on time. How much mass would be needed to have the same effect on time as moving at the speed of light.

Comment: It is impossible to reach the speed of light for a massive object. Depending on if you reach, say, 99% or 99,999% of the speed of light, the time dilation is completely different. Also, the gravitational time dilation depends not only on the mass which create the gravity field but also on the distance between this mass and the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question. But here are a few misunderstandings.

Photons always move at speed c in vacuum when measured locally. After the big bang, there were only photons, a sea of photons. All of them moved at speed c in vacuum when measured locally. That was the only spatial speed. But these photons moved in the time dimension with speed 0. They dod not experience time as we do (who have rest mass).

To experience time as we do (who have rest mass), you need to gain rest mass. Later, after SSB, and Baryon asymmetry, there were particles with rest mass, and they started moving in the time dimension, but they moved in the spatial dimensions with less then speed c. These started to experience time as we do.

Now as these particles with rest mass started to come together into bigger chunks, because of gravity, these objects stress-energy became stronger and stronger and their gravitational effect on time dilation became stronger too.

It is a misconception that mass creates gravity and time dilation. It is stress-energy and even massless photons do have gravitational effects. Now time dilation is caused by the difference in stress-energy between two points in space (in this case one point being inside a strong gravitational field and one outside).

Now as you suggest, photons do not experience time as we do, photons move in the time dimension with speed 0. But, there is no rest  frame of the photon. You cannot say sentences like, from the viewpoint of the photon. So you are saying that photons have a certain effect on time. This is a misunderstanding. Photons move in space with speed c from our point of view (us who have rest mass). But photons move in lightlike worldlines, and for photons, the spacetime interval between emission and absorption is 0. You could say that photons experience the whole 4th dimension in one.

Now what you are thinking of is that objects moving close to c spatial speeds will experience time dilation from a stationary observer's point of view. Say we put a clock on a neutrino, and observe it from rest (compared to what, this is why special relativity needs general relativity), what the observer at rest will see is that the neutrino's clock is ticking very slow compared to his own clock. This is called relativistic time dilation. Now what is a misunderstanding is that you think that you can do the same analogously with a photon. You think you could say that the photon's clock stopped from our point of view. This is why we say that a photon's speed in the time dimension is 0.

Now you say that stress-energy of an object has the same effect on time. It is stress-energy that creates time dilation, and objects (like the Sun) with strong gravitational fields will cause time to slow down. In reality, it is the difference between the stress-energy of the Sun, and another point in space (like here on Earth, where the stress-energy is weaker), that cause time dilation.

Now in case of an object like a star that has a lot of stress-energy, the gravitational field will have an effect on objects inside the gravitaional field so that the object will slow down in the time dimension. You say that time will pass slower for these objects. Actually these objects will only see that time passes slower if they try to compare it to another object outside the gravitational zone.

Now you are assking whether there is an object with strong enough stress-energy that will cause time to stop for objects inside it (when compared to objects outside). There is such an object, and as far as we know, a black hole. The black hole's stress-energy is so strong, that its gravitational field will have an effect on objects inside it so that time will seem to stop for them, but only if they compare it to objects outside of it.

Now here is the trick. You would have to be inside the black hole (event horizon) and compare your clock to an outside clock. What you would see is that the clock outside ticks infinitely fast. This means that one tick on your clock inside the hole would take infinite ticks on the outside clock. This would mean that time has stopped inside the black hole (relatively). This is only theory, since nobody can get information out from inside the event horizon (except Hawking radiation).

Now it is the same with the photon. It moves in vacuum when measured locally with speed c. But you would need to put a clock on the photon and compare it to your own clock at rest. This is not possible, since the photon does not have a rest frame. But let's disregard that, then you would see that the photon's clock has stopped compared to your clock at rest. But this would be the wrong understanding of a photon, since the photon does not have a rest frame. That is why we say that the photon moves in the time dimension with speed 0.